# UIview Intersection with Wheel Type View drawn using CGContext

Tags: iphone, uiview

I Have two UIViews one is steady stationary and another is rotating wheel type.
I want to detect the intersection of the stationary view with the each arc of the Rotating wheel...so i can decide which wheel arc is intersects the stationary wheel?
please help me.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use CGRectIntersectsRect(rect1,rect2)